# How to control requestAnimationFrame for waves speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have to create a animation for waves . I need to control the speed of the waves depends on the availability of the *data*. Is it possible to speed up the waves. I'm using canvas for the waves.

Thanks in advance

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Chaitanya_Kumar/6ztr0Lfh/

```
function animate() {

            if (x > data.length - 1) {
                return;
            }

            if (continueAnimation) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }

            if (x++ < panAtX) {

                var temp = data[x];
                var final = constant-(temp);
                ctx.fillRect(x, final, 1, 1);
                ctx.lineTo(x, final);
                ctx.stroke();
            } else {

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                    ctx.beginPath();  // reset the path


                for (var xx = 0; xx < panAtX; xx++) {
                    var y = data[x - panAtX + xx];
                    var final = constant - (y);
                    ctx.fillRect(xx, final, 1, 1);
                    ctx.lineTo(xx, final);                        
                }
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
```

Comment: the requestAnimationFrame callback receives a timestamp as its first argument. You can use this to compute the difference between the current and the last call. You then perform your computations based on the time passed between two animation frames.

Comment: Is that possible to speedup the waves in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, just repeat what you are currently doing within your animation frame as many times as you wish, probably proportional to the time passed between two frames.

Comment: You don't want to control requestAnimationFrame, but by how much either x or y or both are incremented. So if you want to change e.g x axis movement's speed you just have to replace your  `++x` with an `x += variable_value`.

Comment: @kaiido I didnt used any preincrement in that function

Comment: `if (x++ < panAtX)` Though I have to confess I didn't read really carefully your code block, you may have some problems with your array structure, but a simple data[~~x]  might do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ztr0Lfh/1/ x-axis speed based on y axis data. Closer to 0 the slowest.

Comment: Its just superb .... Thanks For ur  new lesson today.....But i need to increase only x axis speed ...... not based on y axis data @Kaiido

Comment: This fiddle was just an example on how to change your speed : modify the value incrementing x. You can set it to whatever you'll like.

Comment: Thanks ..... Will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sub sampling data

Below is an example of data sampling. It uses linear interpolation to subsample a data source and display that data on a rolling graph display.

#### Regularly interval data.

The data from your question and fiddle suggest that you have a constant sample rate interval and that you want to vary the display rate of that data. This is what I have done in the demo below.

**About the demo**

The graph is a real-time display of the data and its speed from left to right is dependent on the rate at which you call the sample function.

```
  displayBuffer.readFrom(dataSource, dataSpeed, samplesPerFrame)
```

`displayBuffer` is the object that holds the displayable data
`dataSource` is the source of data and has a `read` and `seek` function and a `readPos` You seek to a position `dataSource.seek(0.01);` move ahead 0.01 data samples and then read the data `dataSource.read();` and the linear interpolated value is returned.

This allows you to speed up or slow down data streaming from the source data.

The data reader object

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// data reader reads from a data source
const dataReader = {
    readPos : 0,
    seek(amount){  // moves read pos forward or back
        if(this.data.length === 0){
            this.readPos = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        this.readPos += amount;
        this.readPos = this.readPos < 0 ? 0 :this.readPos >= this.data.length ? this.data.length - 1 : this.readPos;
        return this.readPos;
    },     
    // this function reads the data at read pos. It is a linear interpolation of the
    // data and does nor repressent what the actual data may be at fractional read positions
    read(){
        var fraction = this.readPos % 1;
        var whole = Math.floor(this.readPos);
        var v1 = this.data[Math.min(this.data.length-1,whole)];
        var v2 = this.data[Math.min(this.data.length-1,whole + 1)];
        return (v2 - v1) * fraction + v1;
    },
}
```

---

#### Timestamped data source.

The demo can be adapted by adding to the dataReader.

If your data sample rate is irregular than you will need to add a timestamp for each sample. You then add a `timeSeek` function that is similare to seek but uses the slope between time samples to calculate the read position for a given time. It will require sampling of each sample from the current sampled time to the next (in the seek direction) making CPU cycles needed to seek indeterminant.

The following is an example `seekTime` that finds the `readPos` (from above dataReader object) for time shifted forward by the `timeShift` argument. the object's `readTime` and `readPos` properties are updated and the next `read()` call will return the data at `dataSource.readTime`.

```
    readTime : 0, // current seeked time
    seekTime(timeShift){  // Example is forward seek only
        if(this.timeStamps.length === 0){
            this.readPos = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        this.readTime += timeShift; // set new seeked time
        var readPos = Math.floor(this.readPos);
        // move read pos forward until at correct sample 
        while(this.timeStamps[readPos] > this.readTime &&
                readPos++ < this.timeStamps.length);

        // Warning you could be past end of buffer
        // you will need to check and set seek time to the last
        // timestamp value and exit. Code below the following line
        // will crash if you dont vet here.
        //if(readPos === this.timeStamps.length)


        // now readPos points to the first timeStamp less than the needed
        // time position. The next read position should be a time ahead of the 
        // needed time
        var t1 = this.timeStamps[readPos]; // time befor seekTime
        var t2 = this.timeStamps[readPos+1]; // time after seekTime
        // warning divide by zero if data bad
        var fraction = (this.readTime-t1)/(t2-t1)); // get the sub sample fractional location for required time.
        this.readPos = readPos + fraction;
        return this.readPos;
    },
```

**Warning** I have omitted all safety checks. You should check for buffer end, bad time shift values. If time stamped data has bad samples you will get a divide by zero that will make the dataReader return only NaN from that point on and throw for any reads. So vet for safety.

**Note** For the above time stamped function to work you will need to ensure that for each data sample there is a corresponding timeStamp. If there is not a one to one matching time stamp of each sample the above code will not work.

Changes to the `dataDisplay` are simple. Just change the seek call in the function
`dataDisplay.readFrom(dataSource,speed,samples)` to `dataSource.seekTime(speed / samples)` the `speed` now represents time rather than samples. (or I just overwrite the `seek()` function with `seekTime()` if I have time stamps) this allows the `dataDisplay` object to handle both timeStamped and regular interval data as is.

### Demo

The example samples random data and displays it at variable speed and sampling rates. Use left right to set display speed. The framerate is 60fps thereabouts but you can make the speed variable  scaled to the time between frames.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.focus();
//==============================================================================
// the current data read speed
var dataSpeed = 1;
var samplesPerFrame = 1;
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);  // start animation when code has been parsed and executed

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// data reader reads from a data source
const dataReader = {
    readPos : 0,
    seek(amount){  // moves read pos forward or back
        if(this.data.length === 0){
            this.readPos = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        this.readPos += amount;
        this.readPos = this.readPos < 0 ? 0 :this.readPos >= this.data.length ? this.data.length - 1 : this.readPos;
        return this.readPos;
    },     
    // this function reads the data at read pos. It is a linear interpolation of the
    // data and does nor repressent what the actual data may be at fractional read positions
    read(){
        var fraction = this.readPos % 1;
        var whole = Math.floor(this.readPos);
        var v1 = this.data[Math.min(this.data.length-1,whole)];
        var v2 = this.data[Math.min(this.data.length-1,whole + 1)];
        return (v2 - v1) * fraction + v1;
    },
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create a data source and add a dataReader to it
const dataSource = Object.assign({
        data : [],
    },dataReader
);
// fill the data source with random data
for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ){
    // because random data looks the same if sampled every 1000 or 1 unit I have added
    // two waves to the data that will show up when sampling at high rates
    var wave = Math.sin(i / 10000) * 0.5;
    wave += Math.sin(i / 1000) * 0.5;
    // high frequency data shift
    var smallWave = Math.sin(i / 100) * (canvas.height / 5);
    // get a gaussian distributed random value
    dataSource.data[i] = Math.floor(smallWave + ((wave + Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()) / 5) *  canvas.height);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data displayer used to display a data source  
const dataDisplay = {
    writePos : 0,
    width : 0,
    color : "black",
    lineWidth : 1,
    // this function sets the display width which limits the data buffer
    // when it is called all buffers are reset
    setDisplayWidth(width){
        this.data.length = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.writePos = 0;
        if(this.lastRead === undefined){
            this.lastRead = {};
        }
        this.lastRead.mean = 0;
        this.lastRead.max = 0;
        this.lastRead.min = 0;
    },
    // this draws the buffered data scrolling from left to right
    draw(){
        var data = this.data; // to save my self from writing this a zillion times
        const ch = canvas.height / 2;
        if(data.length > 0){  // only if there is something to draw
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
            ctx.lineJoin = "round";
            if(data.length < this.width){  // when buffer is first filling draw from start
                ctx.moveTo(0, data[0])
                for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
                    ctx.lineTo(i, data[i])
                }
            }else{  // buffer is full and write position is chasing the tail end
                ctx.moveTo(0, data[this.writePos])
                for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
                    ctx.lineTo(i, data[(this.writePos + i) % data.length]);
                }
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    },
    // this reads data from a data source (that has dataReader functionality)
    // Speed is in data units, 
    // samples is number of samples per buffer write.
    //         samples is only usefull if speed > 1 and lets you see the
    //         mean, min, and max of the data over the speed unit
    //         If speed < 1 and sample > 1 the data is just a linear interpolation 
    //         so the lastRead statistics are meaningless (sort of)
    readFrom(dataSource,speed,samples){ // samples must be a whole positive number
        samples = Math.floor(samples);
        var value = 0;
        var dataRead;
        var min;
        var max;
        for(var i = 0; i < samples; i ++){  // read samples
            dataSource.seek(speed / samples);  // seek to next sample
            dataRead = dataSource.read();     // read the sample
            if(i === 0){
                min = dataRead;
                max = dataRead;
            }else{
                min = Math.min(dataRead,min);
                max = Math.min(dataRead,max);
            }
            value += dataRead;
        }
        // write the samples data and statistics.
        this.lastRead.min = min;
        this.lastRead.max = max;
        this.lastRead.delta = value / samples - this.lastRead.mean;
        this.lastRead.mean = value / samples;
        this.data[this.writePos] = value / samples;
        this.writePos += 1;
        this.writePos %= this.width;
    }
}
// display data buffer
var displayBuffer = Object.assign({ // this data is displayed at 1 pixel per frame
        data : [],                 // but data is written into it at a variable speed
    },
    dataDisplay // add display functionality
);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// for control
const keys = {
    ArrowLeft : false,
    ArrowRight : false,
    ArrowUp : false,
    ArrowDown : false,
}
function keyEvent(event){
    if(keys[event.code] !== undefined){
        event.preventDefault();
        keys[event.code] = true;
    }
}
addEventListener("keydown",keyEvent);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function mainLoop(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    if(canvas.width !== displayBuffer.width){
        displayBuffer.setDisplayWidth(canvas.width);
    }
    displayBuffer.readFrom(dataSource,dataSpeed,samplesPerFrame);
    displayBuffer.draw();
    
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // rest is display UI and stuff like that
    ctx.font = "16px verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    //var dataValue =displayBuffer.lastRead.mean.toFixed(2);
    //var delta = displayBuffer.lastRead.delta.toFixed(4);
    var readPos = dataSource.readPos.toFixed(4);
    //if(displayBuffer.lastRead.delta > 0){ delta = "+" + delta }
    // ctx.fillText("Data : " + dataValue + " ( " +delta +" )" ,4,18);
    ctx.setTransform(0.9,0,0,0.89,4,18);
    ctx.fillText("Speed : " + dataSpeed.toFixed(3) + ", Sample rate :" +samplesPerFrame + ", Read @ "+readPos ,0,0);
    ctx.setTransform(0.7,0,0,0.7,4,32);
    if(samplesPerFrame === 1){
        ctx.fillText("Keyboard speed -left, +right Sample rate +up",0,0);
    }else{
        ctx.fillText("Keyboard speed -left, +right Sample rate -down, +up",0,0);
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    if(keys.ArrowLeft){
        keys.ArrowLeft = false;
        if(dataSpeed > 1){
            dataSpeed -= 1;
        }else{
            dataSpeed *= 1/1.2;
        }
    }
    if(keys.ArrowRight){
        keys.ArrowRight = false;
        if(dataSpeed >= 1){
            dataSpeed += 1;
        }else{
            dataSpeed *= 1.2;
            if(dataSpeed > 1){ dataSpeed = 1 }
        }
    }
    if(keys.ArrowUp){
        keys.ArrowUp = false;
        samplesPerFrame += 1;
    }
    if(keys.ArrowDown){
        keys.ArrowDown = false;
        samplesPerFrame -= 1;
        samplesPerFrame  = samplesPerFrame < 1 ? 1 : samplesPerFrame;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
   border : 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=512 height=200></canvas>
```

Reading and displaying data this way is quick and simple. It is easy it add grid markings and data processing to the data source and display data. The demo (regular interval data) can easily handle displaying large data sources while zooming in and out on data. Note that for timeStamped data the above seekTime function is not suitable for large datasets. You will need to index such data for more effective seek times.

Comment: I tried it....but there is a problem with removing the datasource.data array values  and when i press an arrow key ..... Its plotting own value rather than datasource.data..... Thanks for the help